# Unable to assign value of original type in Array.reduce function

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types, reduce

I'm creating a function which takes a boolean indicator object like:

```
const fruits = {
  apple: false,
  banana: false,
  orange: false,
  mango: false,
};
```

And an array like `['apple', 'orange']`. It should return object similar in structure of input object
with properties in array turned `true`.

I've these typescript functions to achieve it

```
// Helper function to type Object.Keys
const objectKeysTyped = <Obj extends object>(obj: Obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj) as (keyof Obj)[];
};

// Main function
const arrayToBoolIndicator = <Obj extends Record<string, boolean>>(
  boolFramework: Obj,
  arrayOfIncluded: (keyof Obj)[]
) => {
  return objectKeysTyped(boolFramework).reduce(
    (acc, cur) => {

      // TS Error next line: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Obj[keyof Obj]'.
      acc[cur] = arrayOfIncluded.includes(cur); 

      return acc;
    },
    { ...boolFramework }
  );
};
```

[Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Why am I getting the TS error while I'm assigning original type to object's property?

Comment: Because `acc[cur]` might be *narrower* than `boolean`; you've typed `Obj extends Record<string, boolean>`, so you might have `true` and `false` literal types for the properties.  I'd say you really only want to be generic in the *keys*, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Na43ow).  Does that fully address the question? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: I think you may have replied but the comment was deleted; could you tell me whether you'd like to see the above turned into an answer post, or whether something is missing?

Comment: Yes, the explanation: 
Because `acc[cur]` might be narrower than `boolean`; you've typed `Obj` extends `Record<string, boolean>`, so you might have true and false literal types for the properties.
makes sense, thanks!

My comment gets removed. I guess because it does not look like an answer. Therefore, imputing some of your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler cannot guarantee that `boolean` is assignable *to* the properties of `Obj`; all we know is the reverse.  This is a concern because there exist `true` and `false` [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) which are more specific than `boolean`. If you have a property of type `true` then you can't safely assign a `boolean` value to it because that value might be `false`.  Similarly if you have a property of type `false` then  you can't sagely assign a `boolean` value to it because that value might be `true`.  Thus the compiler complains about assigning a `boolean` value to `acc[cur]`.

For example:

```
const x = { a: true, b: false } as const;
/* const x: { readonly a: true; readonly b: false; } */

const y = arrayToBoolIndicator(x, ["b"]);
// const y: { readonly a: true; readonly b: false; }
console.log(y);  // {a: false, b: true}, uh oh
(y.a && "abc").toUpperCase(); // compiles fine, but  RUNTIME ERROR!
```

Here you have a value `x` whose initializer has been [`const` asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) and so the `a` property is of type `true` and the `b` property is of type `false`.  When you call `arrayToBoolIndicator(x, ["b"])`, the call signature claims to return a value of the same type as `x`, but the implementation doesn't work that way... and unfortunately the `a` property of the output `y` is actually `false` at runtime.  Which means the compiler happily accepts `(y.a && "abc").toUpperCase()` because it thinks `y.a` is `true` and that `y.a && "abc"` is a `string` with a `toUpperCase()` method.  But at runtime `y.a && "abc"` is `false` with no such method.

The compiler error inside `arrayToBoolIndicator()` is warning you that this sort of problem might come up.  In practice, I doubt this is much of a concern.  But that's what's responsible for the issue.

---

So how can we deal with it?  I think the quickest fix here is to specify that the accumulator's property types are just `boolean` and not the same as the property types from `Obj`:

```
const arrayToBoolIndicator = <Obj extends Record<string, boolean>>(
  boolFramework: Obj,
  arrayOfIncluded: (keyof Obj)[]
) => {
  return objectKeysTyped(boolFramework).reduce<Record<keyof Obj, boolean>>(
    //              specify type argument --> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    (acc, cur) => {
      acc[cur] = arrayOfIncluded.includes(cur);
      return acc;
    },
    { ...boolFramework }
  );
};
```

I did that by manually specifying the type argument to [the `reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as `Record<keyof Obj, boolean>` instead of letting it be inferred as `Obj`.  Now the compiler is happy because `acc[cur]` expects a `boolean`.

And now you don't run the risk of the kind of mistake from before:

```
const x = { a: true, b: false } as const;
/* const x: { readonly a: true; readonly b: false; } */

const y = arrayToBoolIndicator(x, ["b"]);
// const y: const y: Record<"b" | "a", boolean>

(y.a && "abc").toUpperCase(); // compiler error!
// ----------> ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'false | "abc"'.
```

Looks good.  Even though `x` still has boolean literal types as properties, the function output `y` is of type `{a: boolean, b: boolean}`, with `boolean` as the property types.  So `y.a && "abc"` is not assumed to be of type `string`, but as as a type still including `false` as a possibility... and thus the compiler complains about calling a possibly nonexistent `toUpperCase()` method.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAKUWANgLxQb2GBRXGniVQAUAnAewCMsoIDiSVE6QYAXFRgCsoiXgGkoATxgAVSXCgATFAF4UAHgDyDQSigAPXlBCKYAnSN4A+ABRCAXCm2CAlKqtsOHGlF4BXGhAnC1EAOgBrKRg7HTcwMxtIyToAM2DXAG0AXQBudhIAXzz8zm4+FDAaGjBJGToAITo6LABJEwBLTF46GlUNZz1DY1MUACURHsV1Php2kABzABoUBibmMBArWxKSVeaAMWroAHce8MdnRZ2KqprNFLbELD9FJUdEqVT0l2yStxUPIQvCQfP5AuZhKIJNI5ApFDY9lhDpAoKcaOEXKEfIo-MgbNcSDYkIhlogAv9AQSOMSMmSaFk+pVqpJ7o9nq9FKE5k8XrAbHSXHlgcDQQEgsShcKUAUrlKCChQorEciTmdpddBSUikQSlwePx9H18BVHLwaH4oMsGI4UtgYKgChUzHq+JKSAB6ABUpX1KH0jmNPjAim4WEkJpQZotORQQZDIDDKxtdqgMcdnvdRC8Lv44bUTJqdUazTaik6YG6NBs+mWGQARAw61lNV53e6feVJAHY1Bg6Hw2BTebUz2+wnw9aULasPa01mOC7mlBQlg6PMbJJBR72-hB1OU1ahxaCiUzeGgcCN6EwCgAGS3lB1sAMRB1zHdACqcAUNAAwvEoBsLc21jPwQF4dpoD0Koei1TgK0QAALFAbCgNwL2zMolxXNdUJcLV5xPdgyFgBBkBQfZ2kNQhdTKfghEsaFZHkJQ+i0HRBiMEwzAY0RbAcb53E8EVfDFdJLAiKIYlcJ0UKSL5nB+XItWKTDfQLWoGjWUty0rNiBgMLiRnGLgaCmGY5iWFY1l7TZtmFZUjlRM4Lh0WVgQ01kQB5Dl3nktJFN+LwKWErxRXBXjxCiWElARNYVWc9FMWxXEoHUEzJnUfz0itGyNi2fE5SJRASU4ckhIwqUaTpBl81uFkHm89klC5JreWiAU3SlcLxRKrqvBlKljUVUJHJRNFwnVYUWw4bV5xIHM-SNCMo0tJN9xnB1ZJzLqvQ7A1uzjfsVuHGMjvHdbp1naUUAzeb9pQPMbmZIttI6LoemrWsGybGbtwersAccDKzPUH6UAAH0fMA61ypd8vuxdmBw9dNxjFAQN3ZNNsPSNhxPLwz1Cjgrxve9oZfN9Qk-b8oD-ACgJjECuAgOB2mYXo6foGgAEJrhAgBaIXhZFjwAD8JclqWxf59taDoH9eHDAByGmf3-e1lZQENYFIOh+AMdpym4SMWJQZWrtQKGn0p5XQjgrokJQtDiYWrDkdXdc0II9giIKIA)